# Can't install Craft 3 when deploying to AWS EC2 instance - Template not found: install Template not found: install

Tags: templating, craft3, aws

I'm deploying my Craft 3 application to an ec2 instance using elastic beanstalk. When I navigate to "/admin/install", I get the following error:
[image]

When I ssh into my ec2 instance to check the 404 logs, the stack trace I get is:

> 2018-03-02 11:47:03
>   [192.195.80.235][-][-][error][yii\web\HttpException:404]
>   yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Template not found: robots.txt in
>   /var/app/current/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php:69
>   Stack trace: 0 [internal function]:
>   craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender('robots.txt',
>   Array)
>
> 1 /var/app/current/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> 2 /var/app/current/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157):
>   yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
>
> 3 /var/app/current/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(74):
>   yii\base\Controller->runAction('render', Array) 4
>   /var/app/current/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528):
>   craft\web\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
>
> 5 /var/app/current/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(237):
>   yii\base\Module->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
>
> 6 /var/app/current/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103):
>   craft\web\Application->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
>
> 7 /var/app/current/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(226):
>   yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
>
> 8 /var/app/current/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386):
>   craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
>
> 9 /var/app/current/web/index.php(21): yii\base\Application->run()
>
> 10 {main}
>
> 2018-03-02 11:47:03 [192.195.80.235][-][-][info][application] $_GET =
>   [
>       'p' => 'robots.txt' ]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read the documentation about how to install [Craft](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/installation.md) there is no such install process anymore. You just need to follow these steps, install it via composer, run the setup `./craft setup` and you are done. So there is no `admin/install` anymore like in Craft 2

Comment: The docs you suggested told me "You can test whether you set everything up correctly by pointing your web browser to http://HOSTNAME/index.php?p=admin". That redirected me to my admin dashboard :) Thanks

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer in this case?  Otherwise it will get pumped up again and again